# Writing into h_addr_list

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, ipv6, ipv4

I am writing a wrapper for `gethostbyname()` function, which, before returning a pointer to the `hostent` structure, should allow for executing `getaddrinfo()` and eventually mapping the returned IPv6 structures to the IPv4 ones. However, I am having a problem with casting the returned `in_addr` structures properly in order to populate the `h_addr_list` of `hostent` addresses - in case the family identified equals `AF_INET`, of course.

I am basically doing the following:

```
strcpy(&s[0],name);
hp->h_name = strdup(s);
hp->h_addrtype = AF_INET;
hp->h_length = sizeof(struct in_addr);
struct sockaddr *sa= res->ai_addr;

// Segmentation fault:
memcpy(hp->h_addr_list[0], &(((struct sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_addr.s_addr), hp->h_length);
```

Any hints? I haven't written any C code in a long time, so sorry if I am asking a stupid question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, allocating blocks for the `hostent` and `h_addr_list` worked for me, some more context:

```
hp=(struct hostent *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct hostent));

hp->h_name = strdup(s);
hp->h_aliases = NULL;
hp->h_addrtype = AF_INET;
hp->h_length = sizeof(struct in_addr);
hp->h_addr_list = (char **)calloc(2,sizeof(char *));
hp->h_addr_list[0] = calloc(1,4);
struct sockaddr *sa = res->ai_addr;

memcpy(hp->h_addr_list[0], (char *)&(((struct sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_addr.s_addr), hp->h_length);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `s_addr` member (in e.g. `saddr->sin_addr.s_addr`) is *not* a pointer. You have to use the address-of operator to make it a pointer.

**And** `hp->h_addr_list[0]` *is* a pointer, so when you use the address-of operator here, you get the address of that pointer, and will copy to the completely wrong address.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks. However, I am still getting segmentation fault on the modified line:

`memcpy(hp->h_addr_list[0], &(((struct sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_addr.s_addr), hp->h_length);`

with

`struct sockaddr *sa= res->ai_addr;`